# What are the symptoms of rabies?

Tags: symptoms, rabies

What are the symptoms that show up in the person who is infected by rabies, and how much time will it take for these symptoms to show up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with many viral diseases, the symptoms begin [very similar to those for influenza](http://www.cdc.gov/rabies/symptoms/index.html), including weakness and discomfort, general malaise, fever and headache.

The acute period for rabies generally lasts from 2 to 10 days, and may involve itching or prickling at the site of the bite (notwithstanding the symptoms of having been bitten) and then progress to a number of serious neurological symptoms, including anxiety, confusion, agitation, delirium, hallucinations and insomnia.

It should be noted that once these clinical signs appear, [the survival rate for the disease approaches 0](http://cid.oxfordjournals.org/content/36/1/60.full).